# Suggestions for a professional LaTeX book template

Tags: pdf, templates, tikz-styles, mdframed

I recently discovered LaTeX and have been impressed by how powerful it is. I formerly used DocBook for all my writing, but after a Linux seminar, saw the wisdom in using LaTeX. I started using the Wiley template available on such sites as http://sharelatex.com and http://overleaf.com. This was authored by Amy Hendrickson of TeXnology. My most recent publication was all in LaTeX and used Amy's template.

That said, with my latest book for my students I am running into limitations with the existing template; I cannot use every package and when I build it to PDF it errors out. `{tikz}` and `{mdframed}` do not work and going through the template for a neophyte is arduous. Still learning all the syntax.

Wondering if anyone has a generic book template or can recommend something that would provide much the same effect as the Wiley template, but is open for customization.

I'll continue to research more here on the forum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many folks use the memoir class as a building stone for creating books.

Comment: Perhaps you should also give us an example why your 'template' does not work with `tikz` or `mdframed`

Comment: The most generic template for books is *ironically* called `book`. You can any any package that you want. :-)